# Errors in fetching data

Tags: php, sql-server

```
<?php 

$serverName = "180.179.67.205"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"******", "UID"=>"******", "PWD"=>"********");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql= "Select Stateid,StateName from State_Master" ;

$result = sqlsrv_query($sql);

while($val=sqlsrv_fetch_object($result))

{

$id=$val['Stateid'];

$name=$val['StateName'];

}

?>
```

//connection have been successfully created but while try to print  $id and  $name in a table, unfortunately there is nothing, no data, no error.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching object, not array.

So need to get fields as object properties instead of array elements.

Corrected Code:

```
while ($val = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
  $id = $val->Stateid;
  $name = $val->StateName;
}
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-object.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching object so you need to use -> instead of[''].

```
while($val=sqlsrv_fetch_object($result))
{
$id=$val->Stateid;
$name=$val->StateName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$id = array();
$name = array();
while ($val = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
  $id[] = $val->Stateid;
  $name[] = $val->StateName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
$newArr = array();
while($val=sqlsrv_fetch_object($result))
{
$newArr['Stateid'] = $val->Stateid;
$newArr['StateName'] = $val->StateName;
}

Print_r($newArr);
```

**Note :** There should some data in database. Please check also